# How is this equation about pion decay derived?

Tags: standard-model, weak-interaction, pions

I'm reading Peskin's Concepts of Elementary Particle Physics and these equations  confuse me.
[image]

1. What are the $\pi^1$ and $\pi^2$ in (15.49) and why $\pi^-$ equals to this?
2. I don't understand the derivation of (15.50). Can somebody show me details?
   [image]

Comment: Hi @auntologist and welcome to PSE. I think your question needs some clarification or some context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *outstanding* text takes special pains to be explicit on everything.

(1)   He just *defined* $\pi^1$ and $\pi^2$ in the couple of lines above that equation! The indices *a* are Cartesian indices of the isotriplet representation of isospin, and, since the hypercharge (strong and weak!)  of pions is zero, the Gell-Mann—Nishijima formula collapses to a triviality: $Q=I_3$. You *know* from your undergraduate QM course that the hermitian generator $I_3$ is identical to the $iL_z$ of angular momentum, acting on 3-vectors; so, then,
$$
Q= i\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1&0\\1&0&0 \\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So its eigenvector with eigenvalue -1, negative charge,   *must* be $(1,-i,0)^T/\sqrt{2}$, in your language,
$$
|\pi^-\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2} }(|\pi^1\rangle-i|\pi^2\rangle).
$$

(2) He *tells* you the amplitude is equations (14.31) & (14.34) which you have presumably mastered, without reservations or hesitancy; it's a straight plug-in of (14.12)! He just writes down the components of the first line into the second line, and the third line is a simple application of (14.34).

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I got it all except one thing. The Lz Pauli matrix of spin-1 is a 3-d diagonal matrix of 1,0,-1. How do I get the Q matrix you posted from it.

Comment: Ach, no! The diagonal matrix is in the [spherical basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_basis), whereas the $L_z$ is in the Cartesian basis of rotations, so acting on *(x,y,z)* vectors, rotating them around the z, 3rd, axis!

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2574928/362193) is the basis change.

Comment: Got it! I've really learned a lot from your replies!